# Change color of action button

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to know if it is possible to change the color of an actionButton within an observeEvent.

**In ui I have :**

```
actionButton("bell","",icon=icon("bell"),
                           class = "btn action-button",
                           style = "color: white;
                           background-color: blue")
```

**In server.R, my observeEvent is :**

```
observeEvent(data_moment[1,c("facebook")]=="NA", {
    disable("bell")
})
```

**What I want :**

If `data_moment[1,c("facebook")]=="NA"` I would like to disable the bell button, and set its color to grey.

Do you know how I can do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a css rule for disabled Buttons in you css file

```
.btn.disabled {
    background-color: red;
}
```

if you don't have any separate css-file you can add it to your UI with a script tag like this

```
library(shiny)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    tags$style(".btn.disabled {
    background-color: red;
    }"),
    actionButton("test", "Test"),
    actionButton("submit", "Choose")
  ),
server = function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    shinyjs::disable("test")
  })
  }
))
```

Comment: I do have a css-file. I edited my post, can you check that my actionButton is ok in ui.R ? Because `.btn.disabled {background-color: red;}` didn't work for me.

Comment: Try removing the inline style rules from the ui and place them in the css file as well. The are probably overruling the other css rules. Inline are always more important then other rules.

Comment: It works properly. The only problem is that all btn buttons will have the same colors. But it change in my case. But thank you for your answer it really helped me a lot !

Comment: I'm sure you can scope css after id (#) **and** class (.) but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641103/change-color-actionbutton-shiny-r) answer

Ui:

```
uiOutput("button")
```

Server:

```
    output$button <-  renderUI({
          if(is.na(data_moment[1,c("facebook")])){
            actionButton(inputId= "bell","", 
                         style = "color: white; 
                         background-color: ...; 

                         ") 
   disable("bell")
          }
else {
actionButton(inputId= "bell","", 
                         style = "color: white; 
                         background-color: blue; 
                         ")}

    })
```

Comment: And if data_moment[1,c("facebook")] is not equal to "NA", can you custom the button somewhere ?

Comment: @celianou just edited the question to show where you can put the code for customing the button.

Comment: @celianou Edited my answer accordingly. Does this work for you?

Comment: It gave the error : `Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: @celianou I edited it, not sure whether it will work but please try and let me know

Comment: I edited you code. Two things are missing (1) the button is gray just when you hover the button with the mouse (2) the button isn't disabled

Comment: @celianou I have edited it with the `disable` part. Can you post a full reproducible example so that I can debug it and try to find what is wrong with the color?