# When Shiny actionButtons clicked (and unclicked) change color and record clicked value

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Expanding on [change color actionButton Shiny R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641103/change-color-actionbutton-shiny-r), I wrote a script that I'm hoping to abstract and simplify:

I want to have multiple actionButtons and switch their color depending on which button is chosen, then record the selected option.

## Desired Output

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    uiOutput("button"),
    uiOutput("button2"),
    uiOutput("button3"),

    textOutput("clickedButton")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    global <- reactiveValues(clicked = FALSE)

    observe({
      if(length(input$option1)){
        if(input$option1) global$clicked <- TRUE
        global2$clicked <- FALSE
        global3$clicked <- FALSE
      }
    })

    output$button <-  renderUI({
      if(!is.null(input$option1) & global$clicked){
        actionButton(inputId= "option1", "Option 1",
                     style = "color: white;
                     background-color: #35e51d;
                     position: relative;
                     text-align:center;
                     text-indent: -2px;
                     border-radius: 6px;
                     border-width: 2px;
                     float: left;
                     display: inline-block;
                     margin-right: 3px;")
      }else{
        actionButton(inputId= "option1", "Option 1",
                     style = "color: black;
                     background-color: white;
                     position: relative;
                     text-align:center;
                     text-indent: -2px;
                     border-radius: 6px;
                     border-width: 2px;
                     float: left;
                     display: inline-block;
                     margin-right: 3px;")
      }

    })

    global2 <- reactiveValues(clicked = FALSE)

    observe({
      if(length(input$option2)){
        if(input$option2) global2$clicked <- TRUE
        global$clicked <- FALSE
        global3$clicked <- FALSE
      }
    })

    output$button2 <-  renderUI({
      if(!is.null(input$option2) & global2$clicked){
        actionButton(inputId= "option2", "Option 2",
                     style = "color: white;
                     background-color: #35e51d;
                     position: relative;
                     text-align:center;
                     text-indent: -2px;
                     border-radius: 6px;
                     border-width: 2px;
                     float: left;
                     display: inline-block;
                     margin-right: 3px;")
      }else{
        actionButton(inputId= "option2", "Option 2",
                     style = "color: black;
                     background-color: white;
                     position: relative;
                     text-align:center;
                     text-indent: -2px;
                     border-radius: 6px;
                     border-width: 2px;
                     display: inline-block;
                     float: left;
                     margin-right: 3px;")
      }
    })

      global3 <- reactiveValues(clicked = FALSE)


      observe({
        if(length(input$option3)){
          if(input$option3) global3$clicked <- TRUE
          global$clicked <- FALSE
          global2$clicked <- FALSE
        }
      })

      output$button3 <-  renderUI({
        if(!is.null(input$option3) & global3$clicked){
          actionButton(inputId= "option3", "Option 3",
                       style = "color: white;
                       background-color: #35e51d;
                       position: relative;
                       text-align:center;
                       text-indent: -2px;
                       border-radius: 6px;
                       border-width: 2px
                       float: left;
                       display: inline-block;
                       margin-right: 3px;")
        }else{
          actionButton(inputId= "option3", "Option 3",
                       style = "color: black;
                       background-color: white;
                       position: relative;
                       text-align:center;
                       text-indent: -2px;
                       border-radius: 6px;
                       border-width: 2px
                       float: left;
                       display: inline-block;
                       margin-right: 3px;")
        }

      })


      output$clickedButton <- renderText({
        clicked <- c(global$clicked, global2$clicked, global3$clicked)
        names <- c("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3")
        names[which(clicked == TRUE)]
      })
  }
)
```

#### This code is extremely fragile with multiple observe statements to toggle between global, global2, and global3 (ideally I'd like to be able to use the code for any number of buttons) and I think there's a more elegant solution to storing the clicked option than I have above.

Any advice/tips/help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option, using `radioGroupButtons` in the `shinyWidgets` package:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioGroupButtons(
    inputId = "somevalue",
    label = "Make a choice: ",
    choices = c("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"),
    individual = TRUE
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output[["value"]] <- renderPrint({ input[["somevalue"]] })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]